# Regularization of $\delta$ function and Chiral anomaly in gravity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, path-integral, regularization, quantum-anomalies

Mark Srednicki's QFT book presents a regularization of  the $\delta$ function in calculating the chiral anomaly (see section 77 of the book). This regularization reads
\begin{equation}
\delta (x-y)=\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty}\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4} e^{(i\gamma ^{\mu}D_{\mu})^2/M^2}\circ e^{-ik(x-y)},
\end{equation}
where $D_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}-igA_{\mu}$.

Now I am trying to applying this method to calculate the chiral anomaly of a massless fermion in a gravity field but without gauge field. The action in the gravitational field is
\begin{equation}
S=\int d^4x \sqrt{g}\bar{\Psi}i\gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu}\Psi,
\end{equation}
where $D_{\mu}$ now is $\partial_{\mu}+\frac{1}{2}\omega_{\mu}^{ab}\sigma_{ab}$.
Under a chiral transformation
\begin{equation}
\Psi'(x)=e^{-i\alpha(x)\gamma^5}\Psi(x)=\int d^4y ~\delta(x-y)e^{-i\alpha(y)\gamma^5}\Psi(y),
\end{equation}
one gets the shift of the path integral measure:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{D \Psi'}\mathcal{D}{\bar{\Psi}'}=\mathcal{D \Psi}\mathcal{D}{\bar{\Psi}}\exp\bigg\{2i\int d^4x \alpha(x) Tr[\delta (x-x) \gamma^5]\bigg\}.
\end{equation}
At this step, I still regularize $\delta$ function as
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\delta (x-y)&=\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty}\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4} e^{(i\gamma ^{\mu}D_{\mu})^2/M^2}\circ e^{-ik(x-y)}\\
&=\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty}\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}e^{-ik(x-y)}\circ e^{-(\gamma ^{\mu}D_{\mu}-ik_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu})^2/M^2}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
We can expand the square as
\begin{equation}
(\gamma ^{\mu}D_{\mu}-ik_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu})^2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}D_{\mu}\sqrt{g}g^{\mu \nu}D_{\nu}-\frac{R}{4}+\{\gamma ^{\mu}D_{\mu},-ik_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu}\}-k^2.
\end{equation}
Here, I cannot continue. Could someone please correct me? I have already known the result is a quadratic expression in terms of Riemann tensor and its dual. So I guess the square should produce something like $[D_{\mu},D_{\nu}]=R^{ab}_{\mu \nu}\sigma_{ab}/2$, together with the $\gamma^5$ put in the trace, the result can be recovered.

Answer (score 4):

It's just *very tedious* algebra. Expand the exponential function as a power series. Commute all the derivatives to the right where they die against "1", and  keep all the terms that can possibly survive the large $M$ limit after doing the $k$ integral  (this requires going to higher orders than you might expect) and then do the gamma matrix traces.

There *is* a way   to get the general-dimension expression without the tedium:
E. Getzler, A Short Proof of the Local Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem, Topology, 25 111-117 (1986), but this requires some mathmatical sophistication to see how his scaling trick works..